# Return values set on for-loop/foreach loop

Tags: c#, moq

I'm new to Moq and I was able to mock some scenarios like returning list or an object. I'm having this problem where I need to get different values return from `GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess` in loop. In my below example I mock the GetNoteBooks method and return a list of NoteBook object (no issues here). 
Now in the foreach loop, I have this method `GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess` mocked and returns a string (chipset). 
But what I need is to return different chipset base on the mock that I set (loop). Currently I can only return 1 which return a 50 value.

I also copied and pasted the same setup but different Return for the `GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess` but still no luck.

```
var results = GetNoteBooks(); //database call
var chipset = new List<string>();

foreach (var items in results)
{
    var result = GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess(items.OrderNum);
    chipset.Add(result);
}
```

Mock Unit Test

```
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetNoteBooks()).Returns(new List<NoteBook>()
        {
            new NoteBook { OrderNum = 1, Price = 1000, Type = 50 },
            new NoteBook { OrderNum = 2, Price = 2000, Type = 51 },
            new NoteBook { OrderNum = 3, Price = 3000, Type = 52 }
        });

        mock.Setup(m => m.GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess(OrderNum)).Returns(50);
```

Comment: You can call `Setup` multiple times for same mock and return different values depending on provided input. Is it what you want?

Comment: Or have a look at the `Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult>)` [overload](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/IReturns(TMock,TResult)/M/Returns(T))

Comment: @Uriil, Yes, I think I was able to make it by Setup multiple times. Thanks. What I thought I have to do something special on it.

Comment: @WillSmith, Could you give me an example of what you meant? Thanks and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult>)` [overload](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/IReturns(TMock,TResult)/M/Returns(T))

```
var data = new List<NoteBook>()
{
    new NoteBook { OrderNum = 1, Price = 1000, Type = 50 },
    new NoteBook { OrderNum = 2, Price = 2000, Type = 51 },
    new NoteBook { OrderNum = 3, Price = 3000, Type = 52 }
};

mock.Setup(m => m.GetNoteBooks()).Returns(data);
mock.Setup(m => m.GetNoteBookTypeAndProcess(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns((int orderNumber) => data.Single(x => x.OrderNumber == orderNumber).Type);
```